# Spark SQL RDD loads in pyspark but not in spark-submit: "JDBCRDD: closed connection"

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark

I have the following simple code for loading a table from my Postgres database into an RDD.

```
# this setup is just for spark-submit, will be ignored in pyspark
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("GA")#.setMaster("localhost")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

# func for loading table
def get_db_rdd(table):
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/harvest?user=postgres"
    print(url)
    lower = 0
    upper = 1000
    ret = sqlContext \
      .read \
      .format("jdbc") \
      .option("url", url) \
      .option("dbtable", table) \
      .option("partitionColumn", "id") \
      .option("numPartitions", 1024) \
      .option("lowerBound", lower) \
      .option("upperBound", upper) \
      .option("password", "password") \
      .load()
    ret = ret.rdd
    return ret

# load table, and print results
print(get_db_rdd("mytable").collect())
```

I run `./bin/pyspark` then paste that into the interpreter, and it prints out the data from my table as expected.

Now, if I save that code to a file named `test.py` then do `./bin/spark-submit test.py`, it starts to run, but then I see these messages spam my console forever:

```
17/02/16 02:24:21 INFO Executor: Running task 45.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 45)
17/02/16 02:24:21 INFO JDBCRDD: closed connection
17/02/16 02:24:21 INFO Executor: Finished task 45.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 45). 1673 bytes result sent to driver
```

Edit: This is on a single machine. I haven't started any masters or slaves; `spark-submit` is the only command I run after system start. I tried with the master/slave setup with the same results.
My `spark-env.sh` file looks like this:

```
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=2
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=800m
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=800m
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES=2
export SPARK_CLASSPATH=/home/ubuntu/spark/pg_driver.jar # Postgres driver I need for SQLContext
export PYTHONHASHSEED=1337 # have to make workers use same seed in Python3
```

It works if I spark-submit a Python file that just creates an RDD from a list or something. I only have problems when I try to use a JDBC RDD. What piece am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

When using `spark-submit` you should supply the `jar` to the executors.

As mentioned in [spark 2.1 JDBC documents](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases):

> To get started you will need to include the JDBC driver for you
>   particular database on the spark classpath. For example, to connect to
>   postgres from the Spark Shell you would run the following command:

```
bin/spark-shell --driver-class-path postgresql-9.4.1207.jar --jars postgresql-9.4.1207.jar
```

> Note: The same should be for `spark-submit` command

**Troubleshooting**

> The JDBC driver class must be visible to the primordial class loader
>   on the client session and on all executors. This is because Java’s
>   DriverManager class does a security check that results in it ignoring
>   all drivers not visible to the primordial class loader when one goes
>   to open a connection. **One convenient way to do this is to modify**
>   **compute_classpath.sh on all worker nodes to include your driver JARs.**

Comment: My setting of `$SPARK_CLASSPATH` should already do this, but I tried your suggestion anyway. Unset that envvar and ran `spark-submit --driver-class-path pg_driver.jar --jars pg_driver.jar test.py`, and it has the same problem. I think if it were missing the driver, it would throw some other error like "no suitable driver found." By the way, this is on a single machine (updating my question).

Answer (score 0):

**This is a horrible hack. I'm not considering this the answer, but it does work.**

Alright, only pyspark works? Fine, then we'll use it. Wrote this Bash script:

```
cat $1 | $SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark # pipe the Python file into pyspark
```

I run that script in my Python script that's submitting jobs. Also, I'm including the code I use to pass arguments between the processes, in case it helps someone:

```
new_env = os.environ.copy()
new_env["pyspark_argument_1"] = "some param I need in my Spark script" # etc...
p = subprocess.Popen(["pyspark_wrapper.sh {}".format(py_fname)], shell=True, env=new_env)
```

In my Spark script:

```
something_passed_from_submitter = os.environ["pyspark_argument_1"]
# do stuff in Spark...
```

I feel like Spark is better supported and (if this is a bug) less buggy with Scala than with Python 3, so that might be the better solution for now. But my script uses some files we wrote in Python 3, so...